# Jsonpath error when making a filter query - 'Parse error at %s:%s near token %s (%s)'

Tags: python, json, jsonpath, jsonpath-ng

So after running the following test code:

```
from jsonpath_ng import parse
import json

dici = """
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J.R.R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
"""

jayson = json.loads(dici)
a = [match.value for match in parse('$..book[?(@.price < 10)]').find(jayson)]


print(a)
```

raise Exception('Parse error at %s:%s near token %s (%s)' % (t.lineno, t.col, t.value, t.type))
Exception: Parse error at 1:8 near token ( (()

I really do not know what is going on and it would be great if someone could help me!
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use jsonpath-ng arithmetic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65943012/how-to-use-jsonpath-ng-arithmetic)

Comment: Not an exact dup but the same root cause.

Comment: I think this is not really the same problem, mine was related to the "?" character. I managed to find the answer and posted it bellow

Answer (score 0):

So after some days of searching I managed to find the fix. As said in [this github thread](http://github.com/h2non/jsonpath-ng/issues/8), changing imports manages to get it fixed.